# What information in general is necessary to fully specify a multivariate distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

Given some multivariate probability distribution, we can fully describe it with its  density or mass function -- we can associate each point in the space with either a probability density or mass, depending on the nature of the distribution. Such a function is of course sufficient to fully specify the distribution.

It's my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) that in the case of multivariate Gaussian distributions, we can alternatively express all the necessary information in simply the expectation of each marginal distribution, combined with the covariance matrix for the distribution. This leads me to ask -- can we make any general statements about necessary and sufficient information to fully describe a distribution?

I would be surprised, for example, if having a vector of means and a covariance matrix for an arbitrary collection of marginal distributions will give you a specific multivariate distribution. Is that condition unique to the multivariate Gaussian? Or do other families of distributions possess it?

More generally, are there other interesting examples of families of multivariate distributions other than the multivariate normal family such that, once we know a specific distribution belongs to said family, we can characterize it completely with a small set of variables, in the same way that once we know a distribution is multivariate normal we can characterize it with its expectation vector and covariance matrix?

Comment: As your question progresses, the meaning of "distribution" gradually changes from a *single* distribution to a *family* of distributions.  The answer in the first sense is "no" while in the second sense it's "yes, lots" so you need to clarify what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I suppose what I mean to say is the following: are there examples of families of multivariate distributions other than the multivariate normal family such that, once we know a specific distribution belongs to this family, we can characterize it completely with a small set of variables, in the same way that once we know a distribution is multivariate normal we can characterize it with its expectation vector and covariance matrix?

Is that a clearer/more meaningful way to phrase it?

Comment: Absolutely, because you can construct them.  For a standard example read about the [multivariate T distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution).  Very generally, you can take any set of parameter values you like, map it injectively into the set of distributions, and let the image of that be your family: by construction, any given parameter value determines a unique distribution. This shows you ought to state what you are looking for with a more specific criterion than "interesting."

Comment: It would be worth looking into what a (parametric) copula is. Loosely speaking, it generalizes the dependence structure present in the covariance matrix of a multivariate normal distribution, allowing us to specify a few parameters of each marginal distribution plus to copula parameters..

Comment: @whuber, "Standard" families like the multivariate normal or T-distributions (thank you for the example!) are of course closer to what I mean by "interesting," but I see what you're saying. The construction you give also clarifies my thinking on the subject.

Comment: @Dave, thank you very much for the topic! Copulas do seem to describe exactly what I'm interested in in a very general way and I'm eager to read more about them.

Comment: [Nelsen](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387286594) is *the* intro text on the subject.  It doesn't require higher mathematics.  Search our site for his name and/or for "copula" for more.